# Share OrigoDB between projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, visual-studio-2013, origodb

I have a MVC 5 project running OrigoDB (NoSql) with no issues.

I've added a new WCF project and I want to reuse the same OrigoDB. But when I query the database I get no hits. Any takes on this?

Or am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. A good nights sleep was all that it took. :)

By default OrigoDB saves the database in the App_Data folder. With a simple configuration you can change the location where the journal files are stored.

```
var config = EngineConfiguration.Create();
config.Location.OfJournal = "<PathToJournalFiles>";
config.Location.OfSnapshots = "<PathTosnapshotFiles>";
_db = Db.For<MyDomainModel>(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't share the same journal across multiple engines / processes. As long as you are serving the WCF services from the same IIS worker process all will be fine. Calling Db.For<> multiple times with the same config.Location will return client proxies pointing at the same engine instance or remote server when using OrigoDB.